# Losing Object autocompletion / intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

Why is it that I lose all my intellisense / autocomplete references in VS Code when I include `cachedClient` and `cachedDb`? If I comment them out, my autocomplete returns i.e. when executing in another file -> `connectToDatabase().db`, suggestions show up here such as `collections`, `dropCollection` etc.

```
let cachedClient;
let cachedDb;

exports.connectToDatabase = async (dbName) => {
    let client = null;

    if (cachedClient && cachedDb) {
         return { client: cachedClient, db: cachedDb };
    }

    try {
        client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error: ', err);
        return;
    }

    const db = client.db(dbName || defaultDbName);
    cachedClient = client;
    cachedDb = db;

    return { client: client, db: db };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

/** * @async

- @param {string=} dbName Database name
- @returns {Promise<{client: mongodb.MongoClient, db: mongodb.Db}>} The mongo connection object */

Adding the above JSDocs comment above my function fixed the issue. Whenever I cached the client object, it changed from the above type to {client: any, db: any} in the intellisense window and this prevents that from happening now.